# generic generated entity gives 'The entity type is not part of the model for the current context' Recompile Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, dbcontext

I have a problem, it am totally stuck on what to do. I am new to EF :(

I've used [code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/839640/Unknown-Class-Dynamically-Generated-at-runtime-for) from Adriaan Booysen to create a dynamic model. I'm can't use `WCFDataService` because of the limitations, and I've changed some of the code to make it work for me. When I run the it the first time, it works, I get my data, but when I execute the method again, I get the error that the entity type is not part of the model.

What I've noticed is that when I run the application, and create the first Entity, the OnModelCreating is fired, and the model is added, but the second time it does not happen, and I think that is why I get the error, but I'm not sure what to do to make it fire again.

This is the code for `DynamicDbContext`

```
public partial class DynamicDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DynamicDbContext()
        : base("name=DynamicDbContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<DynamicDbContext>());
    }

    public void AddTable(Type type, List<string> KeyFields)
    {
        _tables.Add(type.Name, type);
        _keys = KeyFields;
    }

    private List<string> _keys;
    private Dictionary<string, Type> _tables = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        var entityMethod = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity");

        foreach (var table in _tables)
        {
            entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(table.Value).Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
            foreach (var pi in (table.Value).GetProperties())
            {
                if (_keys.Contains(pi.Name.ToUpper()))
                    modelBuilder.Entity(table.Value).HasKey(pi.PropertyType, pi.Name);
                else
                    switch (pi.PropertyType.Name)
                    {
                        case "Int16":
                        case "Int32":
                        case "Int64":
                        case "Boolean":
                            modelBuilder.Entity(table.Value).PrimitiveProperty(pi.PropertyType, pi.Name);
                            break;
                        default:
                            modelBuilder.Entity(table.Value).DynamicProperty(pi.PropertyType, pi.Name);
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class then to get the `DbSet`

```
public class Class1 : DynamicDbContext
{

    public DbSet LoadTypes(string TableName, Dictionary<string, Type> Fields, List<string> KeyFields)
    {
        var dcf = new DynamicClassFactory("Query." + TableName);
        var type = CreateType(dcf, TableName, Fields);

        AddTable(type, KeyFields);
        return Set(type);
    }

    private static Type CreateType(DynamicClassFactory dcf, string name, Dictionary<string, Type> Fields)
    {
        var type = dcf.CreateDynamicType<BaseDynamicEntity>(name, Fields);
        return type;
    }
}
```

The `DynamicClassFactory` creates the in memory assembly. If your look at the codeproject code, you can see what it does. I didn't change anything there.

In my application I do the following:

```
var c = new Class1();
var Types = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
/*Code to populate the Fields and Field Types into the Types variable*/
source.QueryableSource = c.LoadTypes(TableName, Types, new List<string>() { "NO" });
```

source is a `EntityServerModeSource` from DevExpress and allows me to populate a pivot more efficiently. If anybody can just point me in the right direction of what to do, I can figure it out, but currently I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using Compiling the model. Because I don't create a Database or do any updates, inserts or deletes in the Model, but just use it to retrieve data from a table or tables, I moved the code from OnModelCreating to a static method in my DbContext class, and call it from the constructor, which compiles the model when I open the query. Here is the code

```
public DynamicDbContext(string connString, Type type, List<string> KeyFields)
    : base(GetConnection(connString), GenerateDbCompiledModel(connString, type, KeyFields), true)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<DynamicDbContext>());
}

private static DbConnection GetConnection(string connectionString)
{
    var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
    var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    return conn;
}

public static DbCompiledModel GenerateDbCompiledModel(string connectionString, Type entityType, List<string> _keys)
{
    string tableName = entityType.Name;
    string schema = entityType.FullName.Replace("Dynamic.Objects.", "").Replace("." + tableName, "");

    _keys = _keys.Select(x =>
    {
        x = x.ToUpper();
        return x;
    }).ToList();

    tableName = entityType.Name;
    DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder(DbModelBuilderVersion.Latest);
    var entityMethod = dbModelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity");
    dbModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema);
    entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(dbModelBuilder, new object[] { });
    foreach (var pi in (entityType).GetProperties())
    {
        if (_keys.Contains(pi.Name.ToUpper()))
            dbModelBuilder.Entity(entityType).HasKey(pi.PropertyType, pi.Name);
        else
            switch (pi.PropertyType.Name)
            {
                case "Int16":
                case "Int32":
                case "Int64":
                case "Boolean":
                    dbModelBuilder.Entity(entityType).PrimitiveProperty(pi.PropertyType, pi.Name);
                    break;
                default:
                    dbModelBuilder.Entity(entityType).DynamicProperty(pi.PropertyType, pi.Name);
                    break;
            }
    }
    var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"); // Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
    var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    return dbModelBuilder.Build(conn).Compile();
}
```

The reason that I have a GetConnection is because the application uses Devart as well, and for some reason the `new OracleConnection` used either one, which gave me another error message.

My Entity included the Schema and Tablename as part of the full name, that is why I can extract the schema from the `entityType.FullName`

I hope this helps somebody that also wants to create Entity Models on the fly for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think this is most likely due to that even if you dispose the context you will have some problems with that EF caches modelbuilder stuff

```
public class DwContext : DbContext, IDbModelCacheKeyProvider
{
    string IDbModelCacheKeyProvider.CacheKey => DwContextSettings.cacheKey;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem mostly happen when  your connection string is not right. check the provider name and probably the EF stuff

Comment: I'm not sure if you read my question? So how did you come to the conclusion that the connection string might  otherwise be correct if I said it works the first time and the second time it give the error? When the provider is not correct it gives a total different error anyway. Sorry if I sound a bit annoyed but I gave a lot of information regarding the problem and your answer is not really helpful at all